# What are the various datatypes in Python for very large numbers with or without base?

Tags: python, type-conversion, arithmetic-expressions, largenumber

Are there different flavours of int and float that I can use in Python for largenumbers ?

```
import sys
def add(first,second) :
    return first+second;

ary = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(','))
fin = 0
for num in ary:
    fin =add(fin,num);

print fin
```

I have tested this upto 30 digits value in the fin. Will 'int' work for larger number if I have negative values as well ?
Also, does float have different benchmarks including the base ?

Comment: int will work for arbitrarily large numbers. What do you mean by "float benchmarks"? floats will lose precision when they get large, as in pretty much all languages.

Comment: I meant the range ..

Comment: There's also the `decimal` module for arbitrary-precision rational numbers. If you need floats, you can look at bigfloat: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bigfloat/